# How to detect section and subsection using regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract sections and subsections and corresponding contents from a passage. I have the following code using regex but the code can't detect the subsections. How to resolve it?

```
import re

def extract_sections_and_content(text):
    pattern = r'(?P<section>^\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:\s+\S+)?\s+[A-Za-z]+)\n(?P<content>(?:(?!\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:\s+\S+)?\s+[A-Za-z]+|\n\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:\s+\S+)?\s+[A-Za-z]+).)*)'
    matches = re.finditer(pattern, text, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)
    section_content_pairs = [(re.sub(r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)*(?:\s+\S+)?\s+', '', match.group('section').strip()), match.group('content').strip()) for match in matches]
    return dict(section_content_pairs)

# Example usage:
text = """
1 Introduction
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2 Background
Praesent euismod, arcu quis fermentum pulvinar, urna ex euismod ex.
2.1.2 Introduction to Topic
Vestibulum nec lorem eu ligula faucibus cursus.
3 Conclusion
Sed sed malesuada magna, at dignissim quam.
"""

result = extract_sections_and_content(text)
print(result)
```

the result I get:

```
{'Introduction': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.', 
 'Background': 'Praesent euismod, arcu quis fermentum pulvinar, urna ex euismod ex.', 
 'Conclusion': 'Sed sed malesuada magna, at dignissim quam.'}
```

the result I want is:

```
{'Introduction': 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.',
 'Background': 'Praesent euismod, arcu quis fermentum pulvinar, urna ex euismod ex.',
 'Introduction to Topic': 'Vestibulum nec lorem eu ligula faucibus cursus.',
 'Conclusion': 'Sed sed malesuada magna, at dignissim quam.'}
```

Comment: Is `2.1.2 Introduction to Topic
Vestibulum nec lorem eu ligula faucibus cursus.` contained in `matches` before transforming it to `section_content_pairs`?

Comment: Do you need to use regex? You can just separate your string by lines and parse it that way.

Comment: Are there ever multiple lines (i.e., multiple newlines) between headers? If the answer is "no" (as in your example and as I've assumed in my answer) `re.DOTALL` is not needed and makes the solution unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is close, but there's an issue with the regex pattern. The named capture group for the section is too restrictive, and the negative lookahead assertion is causing the pattern to not match the content of sections that have subsections.

Try this:

```py
import re

text = """
1 Introduction
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
2 Background
Praesent euismod, arcu quis fermentum pulvinar, urna ex euismod ex.
2.1.2 Introduction to Topic
Vestibulum nec lorem eu ligula faucibus cursus.
3 Conclusion
Sed sed malesuada magna, at dignissim quam.
4 addendum
the details of part 1 can be found below.
"""

pattern = r'(?:(?P<SectionTitle>\d+(\.\d+)* [^\n]+)\n(?P<SectionText>.*?))(?=\n\d+(\.\d+)* [^\n]+|\Z)'

matches = re.finditer(pattern, text, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE)

result = {match.group('SectionTitle').split(' ')[1]: match.group('SectionText').strip() for match in matches}

print(result)
```

Comment: Why did you make `.*` in `(.*?)` non-greedy? Why is the positive lookahead needed?

Comment: The non-greedy ensures that the section title is captured only up to the first newline character (\n). This prevents the section title from consuming more text than necessary and helps ensure that the subsequent parts of the pattern can match the intended content.
The positive lookahead assertion ensures that the match only occurs if the content is followed by either another section number or the end of the text. This is important to avoid overlapping matches.

Comment: I hadn't noticed you invoked `re.DOTALL`. Why is that necessary? Doesn't it become a lot simpler without it? Note the example has no multiple newlines between headers.

Comment: This one works, but if there is a number in the middle of a sentence the pattern considers it a section too. How to avoid that?
for example, this line:

the details of part 1 can be found below.

"1 can" becomes a new section. @JonZavialov

Comment: @sherin_a27 I updated my answer to account for this, let me know if it works

Answer (score 2):

You may replace each match of

```
r'^\d+(?:\.\d+)* (.*)\r?\n(.*)'
```

(with `g` and `m` flags set) with `'\1': '\2'`, then enclose the resultant string in braces (`{...}`).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SFQWu5/1)